# How to make all post under post_type to draft or return a 404?

Tags: post-type

We have a client that wants to make all post under a certain post_type as draft or return a 404 display. If possible, I would like to do this programmatically instead of a plugin. Is this possible? I tried to search but most of the SO/WSE questions are fixes about error 404 to display the page.

for example:

```
domain.com/movies
domain.com/movies/movie1
domain.com/movies/movie2
domain.com/movies/movie3


domain.com/articles
domain.com/articles/article1
domain.com/articles/article2
domain.com/articles/article3
```

make all `articles` return as 404 when user access them.

Updated to the code to below:

```
function rr_404_custom_post_types()
{
  global $wp_query;
  if ($wp_query->query['post_type'] && !($wp_query->query['post_type'] == 'movies')) {
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
  } else if ($wp_query->query['pagename']) {
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
  }
}
add_action('wp', 'rr_404_custom_post_types');
```

The code above will return ALL pages except top page and /movies to 404. though my /login will redirect to /wp-login. I do not want that.

Still trying to fix this.

**Note**

I know that I can bulk edit the posts from published to draft but there are a lot of pages/post_type that needs to be changed to draft and return a 404. That is why I would like to do this programmatically.

Comment: When registering the post type, make sure to set `'public' => false` if you don't want them to be accessible on the front end.

Comment: If you've access to WP CLI, you can use the command:
wp post list --field=ID --post_type=CPT_NAME --posts_per_page=500 --post_status=publish | xargs wp post update --post_status=draft
Ref: https://gist.github.com/lukecav/888537e8d2e1ddbdc71ef70ba4cc5832

Comment: @JacobPeattie posts are already registered.

Comment: @Kumar. thanks. will try this later.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth No, when registering the post _type_. Are you not using `register_post_type()` somewhere?

Comment: Adding to what Jacob mentioned. if you're registering the CPT via plugin or theme you can still add the 'public' => false argument which affects existing posts too. This option would make all the articles in CPT inaccessible on front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but if I have inderstood the question correctly, please try the below solution. Articles post type will return a 404 but posts under movies categories will not.

Code goes in a functions.php of your child theme.

```
function rr_404_custom_post_types()
        {
          global $wp_query;
          if (is_single() && !($wp_query->post->post_type == 'movies')) {
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header(404);
          }
        }
        add_action('template_redirect', 'rr_404_custom_post_types');
```